# Windows running programs while sleeping/idle

Tags: sleep, window

I was wondering if there was a way to run programs while a computer is asleep. I know that this may be a stupid question but, i've made my own bot that I would like to run on my computer over night just to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to keep your computer on and not put it in sleep mode. Sleep mode would not allow you to run your bot.

Sleep mode is a power-saving state that is similar to pausing a DVD movie. All actions on the computer are stopped and any open documents and applications are put in memory. You can quickly resume normal, full-power operation within a few seconds.

Comment: So there would be no way to do it? Is there a different power saving mode that will allow me to run programs? Like a script or something

Comment: You could change your power settings profile to save the most energy and even further modify the advanced power settings. Idk what bot this is but more than likely it would be best to just let it run over night like normal. Your computer won't be using a ton of energy by doing so

Answer (score 0):

You could put the computer into the lowest power mode that you have... you could even create a new power profile with CPU restrictions and enable passive cooling only... but it depends on the hardware.

Comment: but running in low power mode != sleep/idle mode

Comment: no, not completely, but it depends on your definition of sleep/idle mode

windows sleep mode is a low power state where most function is stopped but the OS is not unloaded from RAM. in this state you would be unable to run programs without having hardware level access